# Query to group data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table:

```
id | Name | Nick | Points | Date
1  | John |Batman| 123    |2015-01-01
2  | John |Batman| 128    |2015-02-23
3  | John |Batman| 123    |2015-03-30
4  | John |Batman| 123    |2015-04-21
5  | John |Batman| 134    |2015-06-01
6  | John |Batman| 128    |2015-06-12
7  | John |Batman| 128    |2015-07-09
8  | John |Batman| 178    |2015-08-11
```

I want to have output:

```
Name | Nick | Points 
John |Batman| 123    
John |Batman| 128    
John |Batman| 123    
John |Batman| 134    
John |Batman| 128    
John |Batman| 178
```

When I do query:

```
Select Name, Nick, Points
from table
group by Name, Nick, Points
```

I have output:

```
Name | Nick | Points 
John |Batman| 123    
John |Batman| 128    
John |Batman| 134    
John |Batman| 178
```

I am using MSSQL2012 (tsql).

Comment: you should explain how you arrive at the desired output.

Comment: Look into the `LAG` function.

Comment: Remember that results are unordered as long as no ORDER BY is specified.

Comment: Lag() it is what I want - it is work. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to keep sequences of points together.  You can do this using a difference of row numbers (or using `lag()`:

```
select name, nick, points, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by name, nick order by date) -
              row_number() over (partition by name, nick, points order by date)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by name, nick, points, grp;
```

For your output, which does not include the dates, another method just uses `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(points) over (partition by name, nick order by date) as prev_points
      from table t
     ) t
where prev_points is null or prev_points <> points;
```

Comment: @Bart, If it is work for you then you should accept the answer.